# Maintaining staging/development/production on Moovweb?

Tags: github, moovweb, tritium

I would like some guidance when working projects with Moovweb. I'd like to understand what are some of the best practices at managing my Moovweb projects on Github. Specifically how to move them and maintain them from development to staging to production.

Really appreciate the information.

J

Answer (score 4):

I'd check out some of the advice here that walks you through how to setup a professional development environment:

https://console.moovweb.com/learn/training/building_a_site/project_setup

The main idea is to setup your project so that it has 3 git remotes. A git remote is simply a URL where your code is being hosted.

**origin**: This remote will be where you and your developers host your code base. You’ll coordinate changes to your code here and manage different branches and bug fixes during development.

**stage**: This remote is where you’ll deploy your code base for testing. This will be a Moovweb Cloud URL that actually builds your code live so you can QA it before you put it on your production site.

**production**: This remote is where you’ll deploy your final production site that has been tested and approved for public use.

Then the release process would be as follows:

1. Test your changes locally in the browser
2. Push those changes to staging to QA them and make sure they work properly in a production environment.
3. Push those changes to Github so that other developers working on the project will have the latest code.
4. Push to production.